# Django international site with UTC

Tags: django, utc

I am writing a site to be served internationally across multiple timezones.

In the settings.py:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_TZ = True
```

I am wondering if someone from NZ puts in a datetime via `models.DateTimeField`, does it automatically picks up the current timezone and convert to UTC without any extra code?

I am a bit confused on this paragraph:

> The current time zone is the equivalent of the current locale for
>   translations. However, there’s no equivalent of the Accept-Language
>   HTTP header that Django could use to determine the user’s time zone
>   automatically. Instead, Django provides time zone selection functions.
>   Use them to build the time zone selection logic that makes sense for
>   you.

So do I have to override the save method to add the `get_current_timezone()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key sentence there is: "However, there’s no equivalent of the Accept-Language HTTP header that Django could use to determine the user’s time zone automatically."

So there's no way for Django to reliably figure out your NZ user's time zone. It's not going to give you the user's time zone - *you* have to tell *it*! Specifically, until you explicitly [`activate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.activate) a time zone, the *current time zone* is just `UTC` as you defined in your `TIME_ZONE` setting.

When it comes to user input, the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zone-aware-input-in-forms) says: "Django interprets datetimes entered in forms in the current time zone and returns aware datetime objects." So, if you've `activated` the appropriate NZ time zone then the conversion will happen as you expect. But if not, the datetime will be interpreted as being in your default `UTC` timezone.

How do you figure out the user's timezone? The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone) gives an example of how you can set it based on a value explicitly chosen by the user. I'm sure there are also services out there that try to guess the time zone based on the IP address. Either way, though, Django won't do it for you.